# Having problems with xibs and simulator

Tags: ios6, xcode4.3

Im trying to make apps and always when I set the elements in the xib, it looks fine, then I open the simulator running 6.0 and some elements appear lower than they should, or some are a bit bigger than in the xib.

Why is this? I unchecked the "Use Autolayout" and still it appears in a different way.

Any idea?